# SSH Connection ask password for postgres user

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, postgresql, password

I would like to get $PGDATA from server with SSH connection under postgres user but I have some issues:

```
ssh postgres@myServer
postgres@myServer's password:
```

But I don't know the password and I don't want to use it or know it...

So I tried something else;

```
ssh -p NumPortOK postgres@myServer
ssh_exchange_identification: Connectionn closed by remote host
```

How can I connect with postgres and get $PGDATA please ?

Comment: If you don't want to use passwords, you can use ssh keys instead.

Comment: Even if I add ssh key it ask for a password :/

Comment: Do you have access to the server as sudo? can you check on `auth.log`?...

Comment: Try running `ssh-add` before ssh in. Some of my colleagues have this issue where their private key doesn't load by default and as a result, they are asked to enter the password.

Answer (score 2):

I have the solution,

I'm connected with postgres user in my server
`sudo su - postgres`

And I did that, to authorize the the local machine to connect in ssh:

`mkdir .ssh 
chmod 700 .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys`

and take the public key from local machine:
`ssh-keygen -y` and paste it in **.ssh/authorized_keys** in the server
`cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys`
        -> Ctrl+D

Everything is okay to connect on ssh under postgres user :D (or any other user...)